# Лицензия для Linux

Tags: linux, лицензирование

Меня интересует лицензия Linux. Или можно скачать с нета и ставить, где угодно, неважно частное лицо либо организация.

Comment: Почитайте про лицензию GNU.

Comment: [GNU General Public License][1] [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License

Answer (score 3):

никто не подкопается хоть с каким образованием, если соблюдены четыре условия:

1. вы используете дистрибутив Линукса, не содержащего какого-либо проприетарного ПО (кодеки, редакторы и т.п.). Всё это всегда открыто указывается при установке Linux. Просто надо внимательно читать.
2. вы за "ширмой" Линукса не держите машины под управлением Windows. Поверьте, при желании наличие таковых легко выявить, даже не заходя в ваш офис (если, конечно, соответствующие меры по сокрытию не приняты)
3. отсутствуют какие-либо документы, запрещающие использовать в вашем офисе LINUX (например, мне встречалась организация, которой - в результате какого-то соглашения с Microsoft, возможно за определенные скидки на ПО - было запрещено использовать во всех её филиалах и офисах операционные системы отличные от Windows (по-крайней мере так мне говорили ИТ-шники этой организации)
4. у вас есть голова с мозгами и она нормально соображает, потому что могут прийти определенные товарищи и заявить что у вас нелицензионная мебель или ещё какой-нибудь бред.

Помните, Linux бесплатен для всех и вся, а кто сомневается могут несколько раз перечитать лицензионное соглашение (например, вот тут http://freeproger.ru/index.php/documents/80-litsenzii)

Answer (score 2):

Да. Лицензия Linux подразумевает

> - Право на запуск и использование программы в любых целях;
> - Право на изучение и адаптацию программы;
> - Право на копирование и распространение программы безвозмездно или за плату;
> - Право на развитие и усовершенствование программы.

[Лицензирование Alt Linux](http://www.altlinux.ru/products/license).

Comment: А вот в этой связи и вопрос. Много раз на хабре с удивлением узнавал, что наше российское законодательство на столько несовершенно, что использование linux в организации не может быть законным. Кто-нибудь мог бы развеять этот миф?

Comment: Зависит от проверяющих. А так у альтов можно купить бумажку.

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от дистрибутива, может меняться тип лицензии на использование, изменения не сильно значительны, НО (!!!) именно к этому и может подкопаться "проверяющий орган" с хорошим юр. образованием

Comment: А можно пример?